# Count of text as per date python

Tags: python

I've a file with contents as:

```
'2014-08-09':"a" 
'2014-08-09':"a" 
'2014-08-09':"b"
'2014-09-09':"b" 
'2014-06-09':"b"
```

I need to find the count of text as per date and below is the o/p

```
 2014-08-09-> a:2, b:1
 2014-09-09-> b:1
 2014-06-09-> b:1.
```

Below is my code:

```
with open("file.txt") as file:
 my_list = file.readlines()
 result = {}
 for item in my_list:
     posix_time = item.split(':')[0]
     time_val = item.split(':')[1]
     date_ext = datetime.datetime.fromtimestamp(
        int(posix_time)
     ).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
     if time_val not in result:
         result[time_val] = 0
     else:
         result[time_val] += 1
```

Comment: In what way does your code not behave as desired?

Comment: And what is your expected output given the sample data?

Comment: Expected output is  2014-08-09-> a:2, b:1
 2014-09-09-> b:1
 2014-06-09-> b:1, given data 2014-08-09':"a", 2014-08-09':"a", 2014-08-09':"b",,2014-09-09':"b", 2014-06-09':"b".

Comment: Your code cannot match the provided sample data

Comment: @cwallenpoole sorry but output matches with sample data.

Comment: You are splitting str's by `|` in your code and your data is delineated by a `:`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a simple option:

```
import datetime
from collections import defaultdict
In [30]: with open("dates.txt") as f:
    ...:     res = defaultdict(dict)
    ...:     for line in f.readlines():
    ...:         date, letter = line.rstrip().split(':')
    ...:         letter = letter.replace("\"", "")
    ...:         date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "'%Y-%m-%d'")
    ...:         if letter in res[date]:
    ...:             res[date][letter] += 1
    ...:         else:
    ...:             res[date][letter] = 1

In [31]: res
Out[31]: 
defaultdict(dict,
            {datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 9, 0, 0): {'b': 1},
             datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 9, 0, 0): {'a': 2, 'b': 1},
             datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 9, 0, 0): {'b': 1}})
```

Assuming you want the keys as datetime objects. Otherwise you can remove that part.

Or using Counter instead of dict in the defaultdict:

```
In [36]: with open("dates.txt") as f:
    ...:     res = defaultdict(Counter)
    ...:     for line in f.readlines():
    ...:         date, letter = line.rstrip().split(':')
    ...:         letter = letter.replace("\"", "")
    ...:         date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "'%Y-%m-%d'")
    ...:         res[date].update({letter: 1})
    ...:         
    ...:         

In [37]: res
Out[37]: 
defaultdict(collections.Counter,
            {datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 9, 0, 0): Counter({'b': 1}),
             datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 9, 0, 0): Counter({'a': 2, 'b': 1}),
             datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 9, 0, 0): Counter({'b': 1})})
```

Or as mentioned by Alexander, you can use a lambda to create a compound default dict.

```
In [38]: with open("dates.txt") as f:
    ...:     res = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))
    ...:     for line in f.readlines():
    ...:         date, letter = line.rstrip().split(':')
    ...:         letter = letter.replace("\"", "")
    ...:         date = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "'%Y-%m-%d'")
    ...:         res[date][letter] += 1      

In [39]: res
Out[39]: 
defaultdict(<function __main__.<lambda>>,
            {datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 9, 0, 0): defaultdict(int, {'b': 1}),
             datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 9, 0, 0): defaultdict(int,
                         {'a': 2, 'b': 1}),
             datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 9, 0, 0): defaultdict(int, {'b': 1})})
```

This works because `int()` equals `0`, which I'd never realized before, but it makes perfect sense.

Sorting by date and then amount of letters:

```
In [64]: l = list(res.items())

In [65]: l
Out[65]: 
[(datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 9, 0, 0), defaultdict(int, {'a': 2, 'b': 1})),
 (datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 9, 0, 0), defaultdict(int, {'b': 1})),
 (datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 9, 0, 0), defaultdict(int, {'b': 1}))]

In [66]: l.sort(key=lambda x: (sum(x[1].values()), x[0]))

In [67]: l
Out[67]: 
[(datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 9, 0, 0), defaultdict(int, {'b': 1})),
 (datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 9, 0, 0), defaultdict(int, {'b': 1})),
 (datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 9, 0, 0), defaultdict(int, {'a': 2, 'b': 1}))]
```

Comment: You can create a compound default dict: `res = defaultdict(lambda: defaultdict(int))`. Then you can just increment it: `res[date][letter] += 1`. To get a final dict of dicts: `{k: dict(res[k]) for k in res}`

Comment: @CoryMadden how I can sort the result by date first then count of text. I've tried the following code: ordered_result = OrderedDict(sorted(result.items(), key=lambda t:(t[0], t[2])))

Comment: I added an example of what I think might accomplish what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can iterate over the data, and create the required result. This uses `ast.literal_eval` to turn the strings with `quotes` to literal strings:

```
In []:
from collections import defaultdict
import datetime as dt
import ast

with open(<file>) as f:
    data = [[ast.literal_eval(word) for word in line.split(':')] for line in f]

result = {}
for date, c in data:
    date = dt.datetime.strptime(date, '%Y-%m-%d')
    result.setdefault(date, defaultdict(int))[c] += 1
result

Out[]:
{datetime.datetime(2014, 6, 9, 0, 0): defaultdict(int, {'b': 1}),
 datetime.datetime(2014, 8, 9, 0, 0): defaultdict(int, {'a': 2, 'b': 1}),
 datetime.datetime(2014, 9, 9, 0, 0): defaultdict(int, {'b': 1})}​
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file into a list and use a dictionary with dates as keys then iterate over the values of each key to count them and print them, for example:

```
with open('file.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = [line.rstrip().split(':') for line in f]
    result = {}
    for sub in data:
        try:
            result[sub[0].replace("'", '')] += sub[1].replace('"', '')
        except KeyError:
            result[sub[0].replace("'", '')] = sub[1].replace('"', '')
    for k, v in result.iteritems():  # use result.items() for python 3
        out = ''
        out += '{}-> '.format(k)
        for c in set(v):
            out += '{}: {} '.format(c, v.count(c))
        print out
```

output:

```
2014-08-09-> a: 2 b: 1 
2014-06-09-> b: 1 
2014-09-09-> b: 1
```